# java String to Date conversion and re-convert date format dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: jsp, date

in my application I've to set default value in my input text box(a JSP file) which is a date.I m fetching it from oracle database which fetches it as string.So I've to convert it into date.The problem is in conversion. It picks date as '30-APR-2013' .I've to convert it in date then re-convert it into my desire date format 'dd/mm/yyyy'.
In my webservice  I write it like following:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "CurrentEOD")
    public String CurrentEOD() {

        String result = null;
        try{
        String sql="select to_char(to_date(MAX(DAT_EOD),'dd-MON-yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy')";

        TransactionManager tm=TransactionManager.GetInstance();
        try
        {

        tm.Begin();
        result=tm.ExecuteScalar(sql).toString();
        System.out.println(result);

        tm.End();
        System.out.println("Transaction End..... " );
        }
         catch(Exception e)
            {
                    tm.RollBack();
                    System.out.println("Service: " + e);

             }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

now when I invoke it in my JSP page like this:

```
java.lang.String result = port.currentEOD();
out.println(result);
} catch (Exception ex) {

}
%>
<%-- end web service invocation --%>" size="20px" style="color: #AAAAAA"/>

                                  <img style="cursor: hand" src="calendar/images/calendar.jpg" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].txtFromDate,'dd/mm/yyyy',this)" alt="Calendar"/>
```

///My code

---

here result=30/04/0013  In my oracle database DAT_EOD= 30-APR-13

After using to_char and to_date it returns 30/04/0013

how do I convert  this into 30/04/2013

Comment: can you use JodaTime for this?

Comment: I don't know abt Joda time.

Comment: in my oracle database it saves as date e.g. 30-APR-13.I use query select to_char(to_date(MAX(DAT_EOD),'dd-MON-yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy'); to make it date first then make it my desired format but problem is the query return result like 30/04/0013.How do I make it 30/04/2013.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to store in database type TIMESTAMP.
It easily converted to java Date and you will not need conversions. 
(Also, it is supported by Hibernate if you will want to use it in the future)

Comment: I figured it out!! the query is now select to_char(MAX(DAT_EOD),'dd/mm/yyyy') from table_name;

Comment: Ok, in what timezone you store it? In what timezone you load it? In case you store in DB timestamp and value you store is Date.getTime() you do not have conversion and tomezone issue problems